# How to write a single query to display my first record is be placed in last position

Tags: mysql, sql

if i have 1,2.........1000 employee names and id but i want my output as like 2,3,4,.........1000,1. who are in first emp name that should be placed in last ..in this case already i used union all concept it was worked.but without using union all concept
how it is possible?

Comment: Please add your table structure and current select query that you are trying.

Comment: Do you mean you want ID=1 to be last, or you want rownumber 1 to be last?

Comment: i want id number to be in last position by using single query in sql

Comment: id number what?  Do you want literally id =1 , or the first ID ?

Comment: please show us your table structure with some sample data

Comment: Maybe it would help us understand, if you told us *why* you want that one record last. What is so special about it?

Comment: in my project it will help to me .thats why i m asking ..how should it place in last position

Comment: @chandu: Don't you notice that you are not answering the questions? You have a query. That query has (hopefully) an `ORDER BY` clause resulting in an order. But from that order you want the first record to be the last one instead. Now how do we recognize that first record? Is it the record with ID = 1?

Comment: In other words: Does the query in my answer work for you? If not, in which way not?

Comment: yeah..i have employee id and names in alphabetical order..but who are in first emp name that should be placed in last ..in this case already i used union all concept it was worked.but someone ask dont use unionall.u can try with order clause

Comment: So you have a result order by names, e.g. *Bert, Cecile, Karl, John*, and you want this order, but the very first shall be the very last? *Cecile, Karl, John, Bert*. Yes?

Comment: And can you please edit your question and add your query to it?

Comment: yeah that order i want ..okay..

Comment: So it's just the record that happens to have the name which is first in the alphabet to come last. So when someone adds records later, that may be another record? That is complicated without `UNION ALL`, especially in MySQL. You'd have to create row numbers with a variable on the name sort order. And then you'd access that result again and order by that row number, making row number 1 last.

Comment: try it...........

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN col = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, -- record with col = 1 last
  col                                  -- but apart from that order by col
```

Comment: If ID = 1 should be last, this is correct.  If the first ID may be something other than 1 ,  then I guess you could use a subquery instead of  `col=1` `col=(select min(col) from records)`

Comment: @JeffUK: That's a good point. From the little information we have been given, it could be one thing or the other.